# Two step redirect before the good page

Tags: php, redirect

To fix a problem, i need to use a redirection php (header location) that redirect to an another url, that redirect to the good one.

Actually, it works but i'm a little bit worry about that...
I want to know if this works for any context (navigators, devices, ...) or if it can be interpreted like an error ?

Comment: No. Most devices will respect redirects.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using a `header` redirect on your second page as well, there shouldn't be any problems.  However, why not make a new post to see if the folks here can help with the problem to where you're having to do two redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect chain should work fine on anything that works with a single redirect.  The only issue is if you got into an endless redirect loop.

However, I'd suggest limiting the redirect to a single one if possible.  A little bird told me search engines don't like chasing multiple redirects and trouble shooting issues get more complex the more hops you've got to deal with.